# Script to trigger data validation message/warning if cell colour is changed to red

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where productivity actions are tracked, on a 'good day' people change the cell background colour to green which requires no action, if it's a bad day (not met certain KPIs) then they will change the cell colour to red, if the day's cell colour is changed to red they must raise a remidial action to resolve/look into the issue.

I want to create a warning message via a script where if someone changes the background colour of a cell to red, a warning/reminder message appears and says 'Please remember to raise/check for actions relating to this issue'.

For an example:

- My cell range with the data in is RW6:TR36
- If any cells in this range have the background colour changed to
  #ff0000, a warning message will appear
- The warning message would only need to appear if the last change made is changing a cell background colour to #ff0000 thus ignoring any cells in the range that had previously been coloured to #ff0000 on previous days

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate an alert message if background color is changed to red by a user format change:

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.changeType == "FORMAT") {
    const rg = e.source.getActiveCell();
    if (rg.getBackground() == '#ff0000') {
      //e.source.toast('bg is red')
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Type your alert message here.')
    }
  }
}
```

I had to use an installable trigger to get this to work.

Installable Trigger:

```
function createOnMyChangeTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'onMyChange').length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyChange').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).onChange().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you explain your installable trigger please?

Comment: I've implemented both these scripts but can't get it to work, do I need to add anything into the manifest file appsscript.json?

Comment: You need run the createOnMyChangeTrigger() once to create the onMyChange() trigger. The you need to change the sheet name for the onMyChange() function

Comment: And I had an error in the bottom function that I forgot to change last night

Comment: And I just checked it and it works okay.  Sorry about that last change I forgot to add the update last night.

Comment: Awesome this works perfect! Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a modified solution from @MiMi's answer. Since based on your description, you are trying to add a warning message on a specific cell when the background color was changed to `red`. Instead of displaying an alert box, this will add a note in the cell that was modified, including the timestamp when the cell was changed.

### Sample Code:

```
function onChange(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.source.getActiveCell();

  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet2' && e.changeType == "FORMAT" &&
      cell.getRow() >= 6 && cell.getRow() <= 36 &&
      cell.getColumn() >= 4 && cell.getColumn() <= 7) {
    if (cell.getBackground() == '#ff0000') {
      // Add note to the cell
      var dateTimeStr = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
      var note = "Please remember to raise/check for actions relating to this issue."
      note += "\n\nNote Created: "+dateTimeStr;
      cell.setNote(note);
    }
  }
}
```

- In this example, the note will be added when range `D6:G36` background color was changed to red.

### What it does?

1. Check if the modified cell is in sheet `Sheet2` and if the `changeType` is `FORMAT`
2. Check if the modified cell is within rows 6-36. Check if modified cell is within columns D-G (index 4-7). `In your case, you need to get the column index of RW and TR`
3. Check if the background color of the modified cell is red. Create a timestamp string and add a note to that cell.

### Output:

[image]

### Note:

It is not possible to use data validation help text as a warning message, that is why I decided to use note instead.

---

### [Add On-change installable trigger manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added this script onto a test sheet called 'Sheet2' and tested all areas of the range, changing BG colour to #ff0000 and haven't been able to get any notes to appear? I'm assuming this can't be debugged at the editor either because it triggers on edit?

Comment: Did you replaced the column range index based on your expected range? In the sample code im using column D (index4) to column G (index7). It can still be debugged, you just need to add Logs in the script then check the execution tab in the script editor after you did some modifications in your sheet.

Comment: I did replace yes but I also just replicated your ranges and still didn't have any luck.

Comment: did you setup an onchange installable trigger? I updated the answer on how you could add the onchange installable trigger manually